# Can Geth's syncing times be restricted?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have an ISP that provides 5000 GB for use between 1am and 7am. Is it possible to schedule Geth to sync only during that time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to launch a process at specified times on *nix systems (see also: [How to kill a process in shell script which is running through cron?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147221/how-to-kill-a-process-in-shell-script-which-is-running-through-cron)).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a firewall that you can run that is time-based, you can simply block network connections for `geth` outside of that window. `geth` will pick up where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have to avoid fast-syncing as it must be completed before stopping.

Answer (score 0):

Syncing can not be restricted directly in the Geth software.

Some of the other answers give suggestions of possibilities - cron jobs etc.

That said, the Ethereum blockchain is not that big (< 30GB), and it syncs really quickly with the various fast sync [command line options](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options).

Just sync the chain manually between 1am and 7am. Keeping the head of the chain synced after that point will not use up much daily bandwidth at all.

Comment: The chain isn't that big, but there is uncapped uploading.

Comment: With full tracing on it is ;) My point is that even the worst case it is not very big.

Comment: Not sure what full tracing is; but regardless, if a brand new node connects to you, don't you have to upload up to the size of the chain? And the number of new modes is unbounded. Also, what _is_ full tracing? A debug option?